# Left Join makes two counts from different tables the same value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very long query with a lot of LEFT JOINS in. The problem is that I have two COUNTS which do not seem to work together. Both the counts will equal the same value even if they're not.

Here's what I have;

```sql
SELECT T.ID,
       T.name,
       T.pic,
       T.T_ID,
       COUNT(P.T_ID) AS plays,
       COUNT(L.T_ID) AS likes,
       S.Status,
       G.gig_name,
       G.date_time,
       G.lineup,
       G.price,
       G.ticket,
       E.action,
       E.ID,
       E.timestamp,
       E.E_ID
  FROM events E
       LEFT JOIN TRACKS T
       ON T.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.' AND E.E_ID = T.T_ID
       LEFT JOIN STATUS S
       ON S.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has some news.' AND E.E_ID = S.S_ID
       LEFT JOIN GIGS G
       ON G.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has posted a gig.' AND E.E_ID = G.G_ID
       LEFT JOIN track_plays P
       ON P.A_ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.' AND E.E_ID = P.T_ID
       LEFT JOIN track_likes L
       ON L.ID = E.E_ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.'
 WHERE E.ID = '3'
 GROUP BY E.E_ID
 ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC LIMIT 15
```

I won't explain all the query but I think you'll get the gist of it. The JOINS in question are the last two. If `COUNT(P.T_ID)` = `100` `COUNT(L.T_ID)` will also = `100`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try "rephrasing" those counts as correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT T.ID,
       T.name,
       T.pic,
       T.T_ID,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM track_plays WHERE A_ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.' AND E.E_ID = T_ID) AS plays,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM track_likes WHERE ID = E.E_ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.') AS likes,
       S.Status,
       G.gig_name,
       G.date_time,
       G.lineup,
       G.price,
       G.ticket,
       E.action,
       E.ID,
       E.timestamp,
       E.E_ID
  FROM events E
       LEFT JOIN TRACKS T
       ON T.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.' AND E.E_ID = T.T_ID
       LEFT JOIN STATUS S
       ON S.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has some news.' AND E.E_ID = S.S_ID
       LEFT JOIN GIGS G
       ON G.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has posted a gig.' AND E.E_ID = G.G_ID
 WHERE E.ID = '3'
 GROUP BY E.E_ID
 ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC LIMIT 15
```

I find this to be simpler to understand/maintain and often faster.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `COUNT(DISTINCT)`

```
SELECT T.ID,
       T.name,
       T.pic,
       T.T_ID,
       COUNT(DISTINCT P.T_ID) AS plays,
       COUNT(DISTINCT L.T_ID) AS likes,
       S.Status,
       G.gig_name,
       G.date_time,
       G.lineup,
       G.price,
       G.ticket,
       E.action,
       E.ID,
       E.timestamp,
       E.E_ID
  FROM events E
       LEFT JOIN TRACKS T
       ON T.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.' AND E.E_ID = T.T_ID
       LEFT JOIN STATUS S
       ON S.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has some news.' AND E.E_ID = S.S_ID
       LEFT JOIN GIGS G
       ON G.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has posted a gig.' AND E.E_ID = G.G_ID
       LEFT JOIN track_plays P
       ON P.A_ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.' AND E.E_ID = P.T_ID
       LEFT JOIN track_likes L
       ON L.ID = E.E_ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.'
 WHERE E.ID = '3'
 GROUP BY E.E_ID
 ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Having a normal count on one and a count distinct on the other works like a charm!

Comment: Scatch that, it doesn't work past 1 like. The answer below works perfectly!

Comment: I agree, inner queries seem like a more cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Both COUNTs have no WHERE clause and appear in the same table, namely the result table. Therefore both report the total number of rows of the resulting table.

Comment: If you look the WHERE clause appears after all the JOINS. This is the correct syntax for LEFT JOINS

Comment: I meant they have no WHERE clause specific to themselves. This WHERE at the end refers to the complete result set and is therefore the same for both counts and results in both COUNTs showing the number of all rows.

Answer (score 0):

May be i am wrong, but you just count # of thevresult rows, isn't it?

May be  you need to change count to be like

`select count(P_ID) from track_plays where p_id = E.ID`